# C: Go through directory and copy files

Tags: c, file, directory, copying

Given the following functions:

```
void copyFile(const char *src, const char *dst)
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    file1 = fopen(src, "r");
    if (file1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Cannot open source file");
        fclose(file1);
        exit(-1);
    }

    file2 = fopen(dst, "w");

    if (file2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("cannot open destination file");
        fclose(file2);
        exit(-1);
    }

    char currentchar;
    while ((currentchar = getc(file1)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(currentchar, file2);
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
}


bool isaDie(struct dirent *aFile)
{
    char fileType = aFile->d_type;
    switch (fileType)
    {
    case DT_DIR:
        printf("this is a directory \n ");
        return true;
        break;

    case DT_REG:

        printf("This is a regular file \n");
        return false;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown file type \n ");
    }
    return false;
}
```

How would I combine the two so that when looping through a folder, if the file is a plain text file it is copied to a specified destination folder with the same name as the source.

Comment: How do you propose to recognize whether the file is plain text?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I would get your code working before asking how to add features to it.

Comment: ... for example, closing your files *inside* the copy loop probably has an effect different from what you actually want.

Comment: move `fclose(file1); fclose(file2);`  to outside of the `while` loop

Comment: Additionally, unless you do have a reliable way to recognize text files, it's probably safer to open every file in binary mode ("rb" or "wb").  That has no special effect on some systems, but it is necessary to avoid corrupting binary files on others (such as Windows).

Comment: Note that `getc()` and friends (`getchar()`, `fgetc()`) return an `int`, not a `char`.   Your code will fail in obscure ways – and differently depending on whether your platform has plain `char` as a signed or unsigned type.  (Actually, if plain `char` is unsigned, the failure isn't obscure; it won't spot EOF — period.)  Use `int currentchar;` for safety and reliability.

Comment: If you are looking for an *efficient* copy, you will want to checkout `sendfile` in the standard library. Much more efficient than a *character-oriented* copy.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That would be a 'standard Linux library' you're referring to?  It ([`sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)) is not a part of POSIX, nor of standard C, and the Linux man page documents: "Not specified in POSIX.1-2001, nor in other standards. Other UNIX systems implement `sendfile()` with different semantics and prototypes.  It should not be used in portable programs."  FreeBSD has [`sendfile()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2); the call on Darwin (macOS Sierra, etc) is different again.

Comment: Leave it to the Linux hermits `:)`

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions , I finally figured it out!